# Search index of NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsindexset

I need to search the index of a string from `NSMutableArray`. I have implemented the code & which works perfect, but I need to increase the searching speed than this.

I have used the following code:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [mArrayTableData indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSString *s = (NSString*)obj;
    NSRange range = [s rangeOfString: txtField.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(range.location == 0)//
        return range.location != NSNotFound;
    return NO;
}];

NSLog(@"indexes.firstIndex =%d",indexes.firstIndex);
```

Comment: Do you need to find just one index, or multiples?

Comment: Do you need to support partial matches? (the suggested answers so far don't allow for that)

Comment: Why do you need a faster speed than what you're getting anyway?  I tested your code with an array containing 112,000 words, and it executed in 0.023 seconds.  The method I posted below took 0.01 seconds.

Comment: Thank for your replay, You gave the code but i need the search as the iPhone contact - If yourString=@"A" or @"An" it should get the index of @"Another strings" as 0

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your original post -- that's kind of a critical piece of information. Do you only want things that start with your search string, or also things that contain the search string in the middle or at the end -- the code you posted would only find things that start with the search string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method `indexOfObject`

```
NSString *yourString=@"Your string";
NSMutableArray *arrayOfStrings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Another strings", @"Your string", @"My String", nil];

NSInteger index=[arrayOfStrings indexOfObject:yourString];
if(NSNotFound == index) {
    NSLog(@"Not Found");
}
```

Comment: A problem with this method is it doesn't allow for case insensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one index (or just the first one if there are multiples), you can use the singular version of the method you posted.  You also don't need the if clause:

```
NSInteger index = [mArrayTableData indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        return [obj.lowercaseString isEqualToString:txtField.text.lowercaseString];
    }];
```

If you want to find strings that start with the search string, just replace isEqualToString: with hasPrefix:.  With a large search set, this appears to be about twice as fast as the method you posted.